# Program/Script for automatically annotating Java classes

Tags: java, file-io, automation, annotations, sed

I have over a thousand POJOs, the properties of which, I need to annotate properly as per a custom XML parsing annotations library I made. Since the number of POJOs is large, and they are already JAXB annotated, I need automation of <strike>2</strike> **3** tasks :

1. Removal of "all" the existing annotations
2. Re-annotating the POJOs from 1

The rules are simple for (1) - delete any line which starts with "@"

(2) is complex and I want to start with detecting "public class XYZ" in a Java class, and annotating it with @BeanName(beanName="XYZ")

After this, as action item (3), I need to detect the datatype of my variable in a POJO, annotate it like this :

```
@ClassMember(dataType = DataType.INTEGER, memberName = "tripId")
    public int tripId;
    @ClassMember(dataType = DataType.COMPLEX, memberName = "stop")
    public Stop stop;
```

I think a sed script may help too, but I prefer Java, as I "guess" , I may need to use reflection for next steps.

Thanks !

**EDIT :**
I understand the above cases are very simple and can be achieved using regex tools - but I need a script/program for this. If the community can help me code for "simple" cases like this, I can extend for complex scenarios - which "cannot" be done (without a lot of manual intervention) with the regex tools built into the IDEs.

**EDIT 2 :**
I have added a point (3) to make my problem look "real"

Comment: Reflection works on bytecode, not source code. Detecting the first "public class Foo .* {" is pretty easy; I wouldn't use Java for this task.

Comment: Using reflection I planned to detect the datatype of a variable (at runtime), and then annotate that variable accordingly, then write the source file with that annotation added. Indeed, this is not possible using reflection alone...

Comment: That seems like the long-way around.

Comment: I guess you may not need reflection, but instead write a program which just scans through all *.java files, opens each file, finds first line starting with "public class", replaces it with whatever you want and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intellij's [Structural search and replace](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html) will able to help.  If you are open to write some programs try [eclipse AST modification](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html).  It also has some [sample code](http://earticleast.sourceforge.net/net.sourceforge.earticleast.app_1.0.0.zip) to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting link ! I still need to verify this though. Accepting your answer for now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a regex search/replace in all your java-files. In IntelliJ IDEA:

1. Replace `@.*` with ""
2. Search for:

`public class (.*) \{`

and replace with:

`@BeanName(beanName="\$1")\npublic class \$1 \{`

It can be done in other editors too of course, but the back-referencing using `\$1`may differ.